# Window and Alt hotkey

Tags: syntax, autohotkey

What I'm trying to do

```
# & LeftAlt::
Send #1
return
```

I've tried other variations such as (# & !) and (#LeftALt) etc.

I read a few documentation pages but didn't find anything useful except a few less complex examples that don't explain the syntax subtleties. Would be really nice if I could have help on this simple hotkey and not have to go head first in reference docs in a language I'll hardly ever use in the future

Got it>

```
#LAlt::
Send #1
return
```

Comment: Combining two modifier keys without including a non-modifier key (e.g. `#!a::`) can't be achieved with the normal AHK hotkey syntax. You'd have to implement that yourself using `GetKeyState`.

Comment: I've done it before many months ago and I don't remember how I did it.  I also managed to delete the script and all I have is the executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer, as I don't have enough rep to leave a comment. So MCL's statement doesn't cause any confusion to newer AHK users, you can in fact use modifier keys together. The catch is that you must reference them as keys instead of as modifiers.

```
LWin & LAlt::Send, #1
```

The above example works correctly, just as cblupo's edit does. The difference is that cblupo is using a modifier (#) whereas my example references the keys directly (LWin).

A better example, working on the same concept, may be:

```
LAlt::MsgBox, This works.
!::MsgBox, This does nothing.
```

Hope this helps to clear up any misinformation.